# Most effective financial New Year's resolutions for saving or investing?

Tags: investing, savings

It's a little early, but what financial resolutions have had a major positive result on your bottom line after one year?

I'm thinking of going lightly into treasury bills next year. Never mind the small returns, at least I won't be spending the money unwisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of my New Year's resolutions a few years ago was to give up New Year's resolutions.  It's the only resolution I've kept.

Why wait until Jan. 1 to do something?  Jan. 1 is just another day of the year.

> I'm thinking of going lightly into treasury bills next year. Never mind the small returns, at least I won't be spending the money unwisely.

You will be giving your money to the government so they can spend it unwisely.  I don't think there is anything wise about that.  You are also implicitly lobbying for future taxes since the government will have to tax people to pay back your treasuries.  Surely there are "wiser" places to put your money.

Comment: +1 for live for today and no sense putting off things.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped trading in my IRA and gave it pro to manage it. He beats SP500 that i could never do.